# Meteor facebook login redirect doesn't work

Tags: angular, meteor, facebook-login, angular2-meteor

i'm using angular2 with meteor.

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: 'myappID',
    loginStyle: "redirect",
    secret: 'mysecret',
    redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/landing'
});
```

after logging in it always goes back to the home page. (localhost:3000)

my router code:

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
   { path: '', component: PartiesListComponent },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
   { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent }
    .....
```

Comment: Do you have a /landing route defined? What router are you using and can you post that config?

Comment: im using the angular2 router.. added code to main post

Comment: { path: '',   redirectTo: "partieslist", pathMatch: "full"},
{ path: 'partieslist', component: PartiesListComponent } 
can you try once after adding pathMatch: full

Comment: should the redirectUrl property be '/landing' or 'http://localhost:3000/landing'?