# creating a meteor user account from a social media login

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How do I create a meteor account without any password?

I would like to create the account when a user login using facebook or other social medial sites.

`userId = Accounts.createUser({ email: email}) //this doesnt work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[add the accounts packages with the relevant login](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#accounts-ui)

update:
for angular2, [add the api as well](https://github.com/barbatus/ng2-meteor-accounts)

Comment: can u also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741946/meteor-facebook-login-redirect-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment72762781_42741946